# how to use excludesfile/includesfile in ant zip task

Tags: java, ant, zip

I need to specify a list of specific files to exclud but when I try something like `excludesfile="file1, file2"` I get an error executing the task saying:

> C:\Users.....\Desktop\testProject\project.build.xml:49: Excludesfile C:\Users......\Desktop\testProject\file1, file2 not found.

Here is my code:

```
<target name="jar" depends="common.jar">
    <zip 
        destfile="${jar.build.dir}/some-jar.jar"
        basedir="${base.dir}"
        includes="src/**,gradle/**"
        excludesfile="file1,file2">
    </zip>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`excludesfile` is used to specify a file containing a List of files to exclude in the `zip` process (each on a separate line). To specify the list as comma (or space) separated files, use the `excludes` Parameter. eg:

```
excludes="file1,file2"
```